# Handle for Tascam DR-05 to absorb vibration in hand held recording scenarios

Tags: field-recording

A friend uses a Tascam DR-05 for recording radio interviews. His recordings have click, pops and rumbles.

So, I've advised to get a windshield for plosives such as 'p', 't', 'k' etc. in speech and for rumbles caused by wind.

However, the clicks I think are from vibrations in handling. Here, I'm not so sure what the solution is.

I've seen this kit:
http://www.juno.co.uk/products/rycote-portable-audio-recorder-kit-for-tascam-dr05-with-suspension-windshield-grip/456482-01/

But not sure it is overkill, superfluous to our needs with a price that's more than what we'd like to spend: about 100 pounds / 150 dollars.

What would you suggest? (I'd like to see examples of it being used, the catalogue doesn't really illustrate actual use.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to look at is an inexpensive desktop tripod, like the [Gorillapod](http://joby.com/gorillapod) (get the small "original" version or maybe the one for video with the ballhead). That will take the recorder out of your hand and onto almost any surface - a table, or a rock, or tree branch. And the cost is about a tenth of the Rycote.

Next, I'd grab a windshield, but get a "dead cat" style one, not a solid foam one, for best results.

If those two steps don't work, then try the Rycote suspension kit. Rycote has a great reputation among pros. It almost certainly *will* solve your problem, but may not be the least expensive solution. It is the sort of thing you buy when you need a problem solved NOW and have an expense account.

Comment: Accepted for confirming the Rycote and offering an alternative in the Gorillapod, also for the dead cat type material instead of solid foam.

Comment: The great thing about the Gorillapod is that even if you end up going the full Rycote route, the Gorillapod is still extremely useful indoors and with little cameras. One of my best A/V purchases.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Tascam DR-08 which does not have the tripod mount like the DR-05. It's also extremely microphonic, even the slightest touch like having the head phones attached while recording are an issue (if the cable moves it vibrates the chassis and is picked up). You have to think of these things as one big exposed mic element.

Cheap ways of dealing with this.

1) never expose it to direct wind, wrap it up in a wooly sock,

2) never touch it or have your headphone plugged in while recording, set up your levels ahead of time in manual mode if possible.

3) use a sock underneath it to prevent table vibrations from being picked up.

Comment: More good advice here.